# Is this kafka client(https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka) support Aysnc or nonblocking call with php 5.3

Tags: php, kafka-producer-api

I want to use this php kafka lib but could not see clearly is this lib supports async or nonblocking calls for kafka producer?.

https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka

librdkafka which is used by this php-client supports async.

Comment: [not an expert on this, but there's lots of polling in there – does not look async to me](https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka/blob/4a384aa02d9032391980eb711f1928f378f18ee0/kafka.c#L651-L653)